Source for mishkav zachar requires 227 fasts to rectify the soul
I believe I saw in the Ba'al ha-Turim or in the Ramban's commentary on Torah or a commentary on the Ramban that if a person did the sin of mishkav zachar he needs to do 227 fasts in order to rectify his soul unless it will become destroyed.
What is the source of this opinion?

Should we start first by finding its source in the commentaries?

A brief comment is that in the time of the Rishonim and early Acharonim it was pretty frequent to prescribe major punishments like a lot of fasts. Later Acharonim began to point out that this was not really a requirement for teshuvah, as described by the Rambam and others, which basically requires sincere regret and sincere resolve for the future. The rest is going beyond in a effort to perfect one's repentance and service, and things like multiple fasts no longer work for us.

I believe Rav Moshe has a teshuva to that effect, not to do fasts today but to do regular sincere teshuvah

227 = gematria of the word זכר. Did Rambam use gematria?

Picking up on the comment by @Rabbi Kaii "Should we start first by finding its source in the commentaries?"
The starting point is fasting as a form of repentance. A helpful introduction to which is contained in Chapters 2 and 3 of the Iggeret HaTeshuvah (Part 3 of the Tanya) and in particular the passage copied below from Chapter 2:
"Today when we have no offerings to call forth G‑d's pleasure, fasting replaces the offering. As the Talmud says, the prayer of one who is fasting is "May my loss of fat and blood brought about through fasting be regarded as though I had offered it to You [as a sacrifice on the altar]7"[fn7 Cf Berachot 17a] (translation taken from Lessons in Tanya revised edition (c) 2017).
The question of multiple fasts is addressed in the remainder of Chapter 2 following the passage cited above and in Chapter 3. These chapters can be found at https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7936/jewish/Chapter-3.htm and https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7936/jewish/Chapter-3.htm.
Although I have cited Tanya, the material is not Chabad specific.
I am confident that the number 227 has its source in gematria.  The gematria of זכר is 227 (resh = 200, caf = 20 and zayin = 7).

I must say that I am mystified by receiving 2 downvotes and no comments. This answer is expressed to be an attempt to address rabbi kaii's comment "Should we start first by finding its source in the commentaries?" which has received 6 upvotes. Downvoters, please comment!

Downvoters are highly encourared to comment.

Not one of the downvoters, but I suspect that it is because this does not answer the question that the OP asked. It presents related information (which might make for a good introduction to an answer) but fails to answer the question as asked. As you state in the comments here: "I have not been able to find any source for 227 fasts specifically"

@Deuteronomy that is a super constructive comment. Thank you! Sometimes questions on here do not have an answer. But they present a good springboard for a response.  A related problem in trying to answer a question like this one is that the OP may have misremembered the issue. When they say "I believe I saw in ... that if a person did the sin of mishkav zachar he needs to do 227 fasts" the recollection may not be entirely correct.

Right, so I think in general around here a "response" is seen as insufficient to be submitted as an "answer". It may be a well thought out and well crafted response, but nevertheless is not the type of "answer" accepted on this forum. And yes, OP's recollection may be mistaken. If there is reason to think so, it could be pointed out in the comments. Some questions are unanswerable. I say all this not to be hyper-critical, but rather to simply help you understand the culture of the site better and aid you in crafting answers that are more likely to be upvoted and accepted.

@Deuteronomy Thank you for another constructive comment. I am enjoying learning my way around this site and understanding the culture.
